# NSTableView - change GroupRow style

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I'm trying to mimic what the MacOS contacts app does with GroupRows in my own app, but can't figure out or find anywhere how to get rid of the lines above and below the group row. I tried adding my own custom NSTableRowView and can change the background color with no problem, but no idea how to get rid of those borders.

[image: The lines above and below the D & L]

[image: This is from the contacts app]

Comment: Take a look at `drawSeparatorInRect` of `NSTableRowView`

Comment: I tried this in all ways I can think of. In my understanding this only applies to the separators of non-groupRows. I might be wrong; if you have it working I would gladly take a look.

Comment: If it does not work in `viewFor(tableColumn:row:` you can return anything which is a subclass of `NSView`. So create your own view with custom drawing of the text and the separator.

Comment: I know that I can return any subclass of NSView, but when isGroupRow is set to true I keep getting this same layout. If I don't - then I don't get the behaviour where the group row stays at the top of the screen until the next group row moves it out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

Subclass NSTableRowView. Then add a property in your subclass like so:

```
@interface CustomTableRowView : NSTableRowView

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isGroupRow;

@end
```

Override drawRect in the subclass:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    if (!self.isGroupRow)
        [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
}
```

Then in tableView:rowViewForRow, set isGroupRow:

```
tableRow.isGroupRow = [self tableView:tableView isGroupRow:row];
```

This will remove the top and bottom separators of group rows. Sorry I don't know Swift but you can probably translate it pretty easily. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Plus, we can omit custom variable `isGroupRow` instead using built-in `isGroupRowStyle` if you set `[self tableView:tableView isGroupRow:row]` correctly.

Below Swift snippet creates a floating grouped styled table view row -- looks quite like Finder. In which, `isGroupRowStyle` differentiates normal rows from group rows; `isFloating` is true when a group row is not anchored on top of table view; overriding `drawBackground(in:)` removes separators wrapped around a group row.

```
class TableRowView: NSTableRowView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        guard isGroupRowStyle && isFloating else {
            return super.draw(dirtyRect)
        }

        NSColor.gridColor.setFill()
        dirtyRect.fill()
    }

    override func drawBackground(in dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        // do not draw
    }
}
```

Comment: if I do this, on drag and drop group row is not getting highlighted. Do you have any idea?